# Is there a way to tell if the browser clear cookies on exit?

Tags: jquery, cookies, browser

Browsers can be set to clear all cookies when they close as a security measure. 
Is there a way with jQuery or maybe even some server side programming to tell if a browser will clear cookies on exit/close?

Comment: That is a configuration option; in general, configuration options are not directly accessible via JavaScript. It would surprise me if this particular option was an exception.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - I agree but thought I would ask if anyone knew anything I dont.

Answer (score 0):

IF you set the cookies as session cookies (as opposed to persistent cookies) they will be cleared when the user closes their browser.

http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/cookies-the-same.html